# Post large video to youtube via google php client api v3

Tags: php, youtube-api, google-api-php-client

I am trying to upload large videos to youtube via the latest version of the google client api  (v3, latest checked out source)

I have it posting the videos, but the only way I can get it to work is by reading the entire video into a string, and then passing it via the data parameter.

I certainly do not want to read gigantic files into memory, but the api seems to offer no other way to do this.  It seems to expect a string as the `data` parameter. Below is the code I'm using to post the video.

```
$snippet = new Google_VideoSnippet();
$snippet->setTitle("Test title2");
$snippet->setDescription("Test descrition");
$snippet->setTags(array("tag1", "tag2"));
$snippet->setCategoryId("22");

$status = new Google_VideoStatus();
$status->privacyStatus = "private";

$video = new Google_Video();
$video->setSnippet($snippet);
$video->setStatus($status);

$videoData = file_get_contents($pathToMyFile);
$youtubeService->videos->insert("status,snippet", $video, array("data" => $videoData, "mimeType" => "video/mp4"));
```

Is there any way to post the data in chunks, or stream the data in some way so as to avoid reading the entire file into memory?

Comment: That's a good question. I'll try to find out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like this use case wasn't supported before.  Here's a sample that works with the very latest version of the Google APIs PHP client (from https://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/source/checkout).

```
if ($client->getAccessToken()) {
  $videoPath = "path/to/foo.mp4";
  $snippet = new Google_VideoSnippet();
  $snippet->setTitle("Test title2");
  $snippet->setDescription("Test descrition");
  $snippet->setTags(array("tag1", "tag2"));
  $snippet->setCategoryId("22");

  $status = new Google_VideoStatus();
  $status->privacyStatus = "private";

  $video = new Google_Video();
  $video->setSnippet($snippet);
  $video->setStatus($status);

  $chunkSizeBytes = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
  $media = new Google_MediaFileUpload('video/mp4', null, true, $chunkSizeBytes);
  $media->setFileSize(filesize($videoPath));

  $result = $youtube->videos->insert("status,snippet", $video,
      array('mediaUpload' => $media));

  $status = false;
  $handle = fopen($videoPath, "rb");
  while (!$status && !feof($handle)) {
    $chunk = fread($handle, $chunkSizeBytes);
    $uploadStatus = $media->nextChunk($result, $chunk);
  }

  fclose($handle);
}
```

Comment: I am using your code, but it cunk the video and upload it in different parts is there any method to send it at once? so at end I have a single file rather than having it in different parts?

Comment: I just tried it, it actually uploaded just one video for 15MB file.

Comment: Does anybody know how to get the video key/id after finished uploading?

Comment: ... I wanted to add this, too: Without using Google_MediaFileUpload I got the video id from the YouTube service after finished uploading like `$result['id']`. This does not work with Google_MediaFileUpload. Any suggestions?

Comment: Here's another follow-up to my follow-up: The video id is kept inside the $uploadStatus object. Use `$uploadStatus['id']` instead of `$result['id']`.