# How to upload files on YouTube using resumable upload API v3

Tags: php, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api, google-api-client, google-api-php-client

The following code does not work, how can I use it to upload files on YouTube?

```
    $service_url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/upload/youtube/v3/videos?uploadType=resumable&part=snippet,status';
    $c = curl_init($service_url);
    $curl_post_data = array(
        "Authorization" => $val,
        "Content-Length" => '275',
        "Content-Type" => 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
        "X-Upload-Content-Length" => '2394849',
        "X-Upload-Content-Type" => 'video/mov'
    );

    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $curl_post_data);
    $curl_resp = curl_exec($c);

    curl_close($c);
    echo $curl_resp;
}else {
  $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
  print "<a href='$authUrl'>upload</a>";
}



?>
```

please refer to following question which is complete version of this question [Q](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16872701/how-to-upload-large-files-on-youtube)

Answer (score 1):

Try creating a installed application as other in Dev Console if you are trying it locally (you seem to do it so with localhost redirect), then try it as a web application when you try on server.

Make sure you set the right credentials each time.

Comment: I am not sure about the values of the following as well , "Authorization"
        "Content-Length"
        "Content-Type"
        "X-Upload-Content-Length" 
        "X-Upload-Content-Type"  I know what they are but for example I do not know how to calculate the X-Upload-Content-Length

Comment: Rather use the mediaupload as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14465491/post-large-video-to-youtube-via-google-php-client-api-v3

Comment: Resumable uploads are not supported with PHP client as of now. Direct upload will be as good in large files, you can just retry if it fails.