# Youtube API V3 resumable upload PHP

Tags: php, youtube-api

I'm trying to figure out how to get this sample running for "large" video files :
https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/blob/master/php/resumable_upload.php

It worked nicely for a 56Mo file but for a file of ~160Mo it fails every time.
I set my server's timeout to 1h and put the memory max to 1To (yup :3 ) so the problem shouldn't come from this.

After ~1min i get an "(500) Internal Server Error".
[This page](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/using_resumable_upload_protocol?hl=FR) says it's normal and the upload should be resumed but i have no idea how. Refreshing the page, obviously, starts a new session and so a new video upload (the resumeURI changes)

I checked a bit inside the classes (particularly the MediaFileUpload) for method to resume an interrupted upload with no success..

Am i missing something.?

Comment: Mmmm just saw the last comment of this post, made by the author of the github's API samples, that the resumable upload are not supported by PHP.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17008987/how-to-upload-files-on-youtube-using-resumable-upload-api-v3

But the post was made a year ago, is it still the case.?

Answer (score 0):

I've found no solution for my problem and went for a totally different one with this Python script :
https://code.google.com/p/youtube-upload/wiki/Readme

And it's better as it does what i wanted, no need for Youtube API, just need the login/password of an account and it uploads the video on it. Which is exatly what i wanted :D !