# Google API's php client library - YouTube chunked upload ERROR

Tags: php, youtube, youtube-api, google-api-php-client

I'm using Google API's PHP client library and when I use this solution:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/14552052/1181479
and the same as here
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/php#resumable_uploads

witch contain such logic:

```
if ($client->getAccessToken()) {
  $videoPath = "path/to/foo.mp4";
  $snippet = new Google_VideoSnippet();
  $snippet->setTitle("Test title2");
  $snippet->setDescription("Test descrition");
  $snippet->setTags(array("tag1", "tag2"));
  $snippet->setCategoryId("22");

  $status = new Google_VideoStatus();
  $status->privacyStatus = "private";

  $video = new Google_Video();
  $video->setSnippet($snippet);
  $video->setStatus($status);

  $chunkSizeBytes = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
  $media = new Google_MediaFileUpload('video/mp4', null, true, $chunkSizeBytes);
  $media->setFileSize(filesize($videoPath));

  $result = $youtube->videos->insert("status,snippet", $video,
      array('mediaUpload' => $media));

  $status = false;
  $handle = fopen($videoPath, "rb");
  while (!$status && !feof($handle)) {
    $chunk = fread($handle, $chunkSizeBytes);
    $uploadStatus = $media->nextChunk($result, $chunk);
  }

  fclose($handle);
}
```

The main problem is this error:

> ErrorException [ Recoverable Error ]: Argument 1 passed to Google_MediaFileUpload::nextChunk() must be an instance of Google_HttpRequest, instance of Google_Video given, called in /opt/code/host/resulinkpro/www/application/classes/Controller/Upload.php on line 132 and defined

the core of that stuff is:
**$media** is Google_Video class
and

```
$media->nextChunk($result, $chunk);
```

requires **$result** to be Google_HttpRequest SO Google documentation and any example in web will not help to achieve that task at all! Last chance on you guys!
Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Both of the examples were made for PHP client 0.6.3, I believe you are trying it with 1.0 version. You can read about [migrating here](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/guide/migration).

We hope to post the updated examples really soon.

Comment: ok will try to use that guide some time later. Tank you for pointing!

Comment: I am using the older PHP client but getting exactly the same error.  I will assume there is a mismatch between the examples and the API and wait for the examples to catch up.  You would think that they would be updated at the same time.

Comment: They got updated indeed. https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/blob/master/php/resumable_upload.php